# Documenting a Spring HATEOAS API

Tags: api, rest, documentation, spring-hateoas

Are there any plugins out there (similar to Swagger) which provide the ability to document HATEOAS APIs?

The Swagger interface is quite good but it doesn't have level 3 REST support.

Comment: @GhostCat I figured it was a pretty ridiculous question after my head re-emerged from the DI rabbit hole and I could see it for what it was.

Comment: Well, I can live with that... And well this question is worth upvoting too ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation I discovered HAL-browser (https://github.com/mikekelly/hal-browser) which is quite good.  Although, your API must return content-type of HAL for it.

You don't need to configure anything on the server for this tool.  Just open it in a browser and point to your API.

Comment: The HAL Browser is now a module you can install with maven coordinates org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser.

Answer (score 3):

I use [spring-restdocs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs) in combination with the HAL-browser.

You don't necessarily need HAL for restdocs though, although it is recommended.

Restdocs will generate code samples and link & field descriptors in the asciidoc format. You can then link to these asciidocs from inside the HAL-browser.

To see the result in action (although this is hardcoded), check this out: [foxycart](https://api-sandbox.foxycart.com/hal-browser/browser.html#/). Click on the little doc links next to the rels.